# Is there a way to keep files even when using --alluredir

Tags: python, junit, pytest, allure

So I have to create an Allure Report using pytest with an junit xml file. I invoke the pytest.main() from my test_config.py file to start different types of testcases within different folders.

```
def start_pytest(args):

if pytest.main(["-x", "--alluredir=%s" % allure_path, "--junitxml=%s" % junit_path, test_1]):
    sys.exit(1)

if args.test2 or args.all:
    pytest.main(["--alluredir=%s" % allure_path, "--junitxml=%s" % junit_path, test_2])

if args.test3 or args.all:
    pytest.main(["--alluredir=%s" % allure_path, "--junitxml=%s" % junit_path, test_3])
```

I think i need the --alluredir=somepath option to create an XML file to be used by Allure. And I want to have different test_case.py files if possible. The problem now is, if I use --alluredir a second or third time in my script the report directory will be purged:

```
py.test --alluredir [path_to_report_dir]
# WARNING [path_to_report_dir] will be purged at first run
```

source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-allure-adaptor

So, is there a way to delete the directory the first time use --allurdir and keep the files the second and third time around. Or do I have to write all testcases in one file so I only have to call pytest.main() one time.

Thank you for your time, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allure can make one report from a number of test results.

But py.test allure adapter clears the result directory before run.

So you have to collect results in different directories and after that place them into one directory before report generation.

But of cause that should be different sets of test-cases.

Comment: Thank you, thats what i figured out to. But i didnt place them all in one directory, i just let allure search for all .xml testresult files and put them all into the final report.